# Joining/Merging records from two non related tables based on specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, inner-join, union

I have two tables:

- Items

  - ItemId PK - primary key
  - UPC,
  - EAN
- TDItems

  - TdItemsId PK --  primary key
  - UPC,
  - EAN

These two tables are not related in my DB via FK constraint.

The tables contains items who share same information based on which I want to join/union them: UPC and EAN columns

I have tried doing a simple query like this:

```
select * 
from Items as It join TDItems as tdi
on it.UPC=tdi.UPC and it.EAN=tdi.EAN
```

This query returns "some" results, however when I did a union of two queries like this:

```
  select * 
    from Items as It join TDItems as tdi
    on it.UPC=tdi.UPC 

    UNION -- important part I guess?

    select * 
    from Items as It join TDItems as tdi
    on it.EAN=tdi.EAN
```

First query returns 504 results, and second query returns 709 results...

So my questions are:

1. Why does first query returns less results when it should be the same?
2. How would I make this query so that it returns the amount of rows that it found (ie. 504, 600 or whatever number it may be?)

Can someone help me out to write a proper query for these issues?

Edit:

Hey @Gordon I have rewritten the inner join

```
select * 
from Items as It join TDItems as tdi
on it.UPC=tdi.UPC OR it.EAN=tdi.EAN
```

Would this be the solution to have the items match either on UPC or EAN (ie doesn't have to be pair of matched UPC and EAN)

Answer (score 2):

The `UNION` is more like an `OR`

The query would be more like the UNION

```
select * 
from Items as It 
join TDItems as tdi
  on it.UPC = tdi.UPC 
  or it.EAN = tdi.EAN
```

Comment: Hey I just tried this query, and it takes significantly much more time to load data rather than just with AND statement :/

Comment: P.S. Just tested execution time, it takes 1 minute and 36 seconds to execute, lolz..

Comment: OR is consistently slower than AND

Comment: is there any workaround to that ? I mean 1 minute and 36 seconds for a query is just catastrophic lol

Comment: Not really.  You may want to post the table definition and query plan in a separate question?

Comment: the table currently only has those columns up there... I'm writing a query against those two to test the performance.. Are you sure that there isnt ? Maybe indexing the columns would speed things up? Is then a 2nd query a better solution with union ??

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

I see no reason why the queries would return the same number of rows.  That just depends on the data.  For instance, the first query could return no rows if no pairs of `UPC`/`EAN` are in common between the two tables, but the two tables do have common `UPC` and `EAN` values independently.

As for your second question, you seem to want `select count(*)` instead of `select item`.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for the reply ! So basically when I do on UPC=UPC and EAN=EAN ... They have to be paired up in order to be returned ? But what if for example UPC's match for a single item and EAN's don't , the item wouldn't be returned? 

Ah yes Select count(*) is simplest indeed... But I wanna return both item and count of returned records:P

I wanna do a single inner join where a single item would either match on UPC from another table or either on EAN and return it as result? How can that be done ?^^

Comment: I've edited my question and I just replaced the AND with OR in between the join on ON statement. The query with OR takes significantly much more time to execute rather than AND one...